# How do I show an image into a window's client area in Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Given an RGBA array (24 bpp) of an image that has the same width and height of a window's client area, how do I efficiently show that image on that client area, using the Win32 API?

Can I use the same function(s) to efficiently update part of the window's client area with a changed sub-image? If not, which other functions should I use?

I own the window of which I'm trying to modify the client area.

I tried by using these functions:

1. Creating a compatible device context (with `CreateCompatibleDC`)
2. Creating a compatible bitmap (with `CreateCompatibleBitmap`)
3. Selecting the bitmap (with `SelectObject`)
4. Getting the bitmap object info (with `GetObject`)
5. Setting the bitmap bits (with `SetDIBits`) because CreateCompatibleBitmap does not allow to specify bits as a function argument
6. Transferring the color data to the device context (with `BitBlt`)

But the result I got does not match my expectations at all.

This is what I got:

[image]

What I expected was the client area divided in 4 equal parts, each one with a different shade of gray (white, light gray, dark gray, black).

I also tried using [`SetDIBitsToDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setdibitstodevice) and removing the alpha channel, but the result is the same.

I suspect that the actual problem is the channel order, as if Win32 didn't use RGB but BGR or others.

Comment: Win32 does indeed use BGR (or BGRA).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd probably use [`CreateDIBSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection).

This creates a DIB Section object, which allows both direct access to its memory *and* use as a device independent bitmap, so you can create it, copy your data into its memory, then use it with `BitBlt` (and similar such as `StretchBlt`, `PlgBlt`, etc.) just like any other device independent bitmap supports.

A typical call to CreateDIBSection will look something like this:

```
BITMAPINFO info {};
info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(info.bmiHeader);
info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
info.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
info.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;

DWORD *pixels;

HBITMAP section = CreateDIBSection(mem, &info, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void **)&pixels, NULL, 0);
```

At this point you have an HBITMAP, which you can use to do all the normal bitmap stuff (e.g., select it into a `DC`,then `BitBlit` to/from it).

But you also have `pixels`, which is a pointer directly to the memory that contains the data for that bitmap. The one thing to look out for here is that you need to call `GdiFlush()` before trying to access that memory directly (to give GDI a chance to finish if it's already using it).

Now don't get me wrong: if you get the format correct, it's certainly entirely possible to make `SetDIBIts` work as well. But at least personally, I find DIB Sections less annoying to deal with.

Oh, one other minor detail: I'd advise always using 32 bits per pixel instead of 24. This eliminates any need to pad the data (which can be mildly annoying), and usually blits faster as well (one dword per pixel is easy to manipulate, display, etc.)

Comment: In this case, what should I put in `CreateDIBSection`'s `hSection` and `offset` (the 5th and 6th parameters), and in `BitBlt`'s `hdcSrc` (the 6th parameter)?

Comment: @IInspectable: Oops--you are (of course) completely correct.

Comment: @Edoardo: I've added a bit of code to demonstrate a typical call to `CreateDIBSection`. Just like any other time you use `BitBlt`, you typically start by calling `CreateCompatibleDC` to create a DC compatible with the screen (or printer, etc.), select the `HBITMAP` returned from `CreateDIBSection` into that compatible DC, then pass the handle to that DC as the source in your call to `BitBlt`.

Comment: I tried to do what you said, but I still get the same result as before and it is very slow at copying all the pixels from my buffer into the pixels array. Maybe it would be easier and more efficient if I just drew a one-pixel rectangle for each pixel?

Comment: @Edoardo: It's starting to sound like you may simply have somewhat unrealistic hopes for how fast this could be. There may be other approaches that improve speed a little, but DIB Sections were designed specifically for this this use-case, so it's unlikely GDI has anything that'll do it a lot faster. To get a lot faster you may need to move to something like DirectX/OpenGL/Vulkan.

Comment: Sorry for my insistence but why would drawing pixels be so slow?

Comment: @Edoardo: how slow is it, and how fast are you hoping for?